# Get count of rows in table A that have a reference to table B

Tags: mysql, sql, scala, slick

I am left joining two tables, 'device' and 'unit'. Device defines the type of device and an unit is an unique device that points to a row in the device table, defining its type.

I am now searching for a solution to select every device type from 'device' and counting how many units are there pointing to this device. The problem I am confronted with in my current solution,

**SQL**:

```
SELECT device.*, COUNT(unit.id) 
FROM device LEFT JOIN unit ON device.id = unit.device_id GROUPBY device.id
```

**Scala Slick**:

```
def devicesWithUnitCount = for {
    (device, unit) <- TableQuery[TDDevice] joinLeft TableQuery[TDUnit] 
                                           on (_.id === _.deviceID) 
                                           groupBy (_._1)
} yield (device, unit.size)
```

is that I get a count result of at least 1, even if there is no unit pointing to the device type.

How can I achieve this counting in SQL, or preferably Slick?

Comment: use deviceid instead of device.*?

Comment: How would that fix the counting issue?

Comment: imagine you would get a row with values 1,2,someval1,someval2,null.. where 1 is the deviceid. This would still result in count being 1

Comment: But I _need_ the information provided by device.*, I just want to additionally get the count of units pointing to device.id

Comment: see if the answer gets you what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is correct for what you want to do.  Slick is probably producing a query like this:

```
SELECT device.*, COUNT(device.id) 
-----------------------^
FROM device LEFT JOIN
     unit
     ON device.id = unit.device_id
GROUP BY device.id;
```

Maybe there is a way to get it to count `device_id`, which is unamibiguously from `unit`.

Comment: I didn't even notice that the SQL statement I was using already did what it was supposed to do, because I thought my Slick implementation was correct. Thanks for the hint.