# Implementing a complex left join in Scala Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I was searching for a specific SQL that I found here on stackoverflow ([Get count of rows in table A that have a reference to table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813118/get-count-of-rows-in-table-a-that-have-a-reference-to-table-b/32813332#32813332))

However I seem to be unable to implement this SQL solution in Slick.

```
SELECT device.*, c.cnt
 FROM device 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT device_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
             FROM unit 
             GROUP BY device_id) c 
 ON device.id = c.device_id
```

My current approach fails with

```
slick.SlickException: Unexpected node Select _2 -- SQL prefix: select x2.x3, x2.x4, x2.x5, x2.x6,
```

when trying to run/compile the query

```
val devicesWithUnitCountResult = dbConfig.db.run(TableQueries.devicesWithUnitCount.result)
```

Current code:

```
  def unitCountPerDevice = for {
    (id, length) <- TableQuery[TDUnit].groupBy(k => k.deviceID).map(k => (k._1, k._2.map(_.id).length))
  } yield (id, length)

  def devicesWithUnitCount = for {
    (device, unitcount) <- TableQuery[TDDevice].joinLeft(unitCountPerDevice).on(_.id === _._1).map(k => {
      val u = k._2.getOrElse((0, 0))._2
      (k._1, u)
    })
  } yield (device, unitcount)
```

Can somebody help me to find out where I am failing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
def unitCountPerDevice = TableQuery[TDUnit].groupBy(k => k.deviceID).map(k => (k._1, k._2.map(_.id).length))

def devicesWithUnitCount = TableQuery[TDDevice].joinLeft(unitCountPerDevice).on(_.id === _._1).map(d =>(d._1,d._2.map(_._2)))
```