# Slick count (.length / .size) doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am using the following Slick code to implement an SQL statement.

**SQL**:

```
SELECT device.*, COUNT(unit.id) AS cnt 
FROM device LEFT JOIN unit ON device.id = unit.device_id GROUP BY device.id;
```

**Scala Slick**:

```
def devicesWithUnitCount = for {
    (device, unit) <- TableQuery[TDDevice] joinLeft TableQuery[TDUnit] 
                                           on (_.id === _.deviceID) 
                                           groupBy (_._1)
} yield (device, unit.size)
```

Sample schema, I couldn't get the query to work there, but it does on my server.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f335

However, unlike the SQL statement, which is correctly returning 0, the slick implementation yields a count of 1 even if there is no associated row in unit.

As I already thought it is the SQL statement I asked for help ([Get count of rows in table A that have a reference to table B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813118/get-count-of-rows-in-table-a-that-have-a-reference-to-table-b)) and got told that the SQL statement should work fine (double checked that, and confirmed that it works). Now with the help of that answer I know now that my Slick implementation has to be wrong, and my question is how I can fix the slick query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Slick documentation for [groupBy](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql-to-slick.html#group-by), which says:

> a groupBy call must be followed by a map call

So I guess this would do the trick for you:

```
 def devicesWithUnitCount = (
    TableQuery[TDDevice] joinLeft TableQuery[TDUnit] 
      on (_.id === _.deviceID) ) 
    .groupBy (_._1)
    .map{ case (grouped, all) => (grouped, all.map(_._2).size) }
```